# Does iOS 6 or any other iOS OS have drivers or kernel modules for an HP printer?

Tags: printing

I want to print via USB, but iOS does not mention the interface when I connect directly to my non-Wi-Fi printer.

REALIZE: I do not want to print wirelessly I want to do so via USB, but iOS apparently does not have drivers/kernel extendablr modules to support printing like this, such as with Lion.

Any workarounds? Any device drivers?

I will write one myself if there is no program to help with this.

Comment: No. You need to purchase a printer that is Apple AirPrint-compatible, or purchase a printer that provides an iOS app for printing from an iOS device. The Brother printer company, for instance, has such an app.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Source of everything I'm about to say: I'm an iOS developer.</sub>

## No.

Your iOS device does **not** contain the necessary drivers to print via USB - and here's why:

### Developers

We are kind of, well, lazy. We don't want to write more code than we have to - we want to write one thing once and have it work.

Now imagine all the iOS devs now have to take into account that you can print from USB. Now we might have to write code to take that into account, there might be subtle differences in the drivers, etc.

The nice thing about AirPrint is it *just works*. Not just from the *user's* standpoint, but also from the *developer's* standpoint. Developers can basically 'layout' the paper just like they would a bunch of views onscreen, send it to a print controller, and let it handle everything else.

Nice and easy.

### You

You're a user. You want things to just *work*, right? Even as a developer, I want the stuff I'm using to just work (See [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) for thousands of examples).

If Apple put in kernel drivers and USB printer drivers and all whatnot, the *user* now has to manage that, and *Apple* has to conform to HP's, Canon's and Brother's requirements.
With AirPrint, the *manufacturer* conforms to *Apple* - a much better experience for you and me, the users.

Comment: are you trying to change my mind? Because, mark my words, I CAN do it all by myself and get what I want done, and spread the freeware around, including any necessary Hackintoshing around as well. Try me.

Comment: @Mandy Go for it! Have any previous dev background?

Answer (score 0):

The only printing ability native to iOS is AirPrint which requires either an AirPrint enabled printer in your WLAN or a AirPrint driver on your Mac/Windows computer.

Comment: Then I can write my own USB/HP driver and UI app for direct printing and interfacing via USB from iPhone?

Comment: I don't know to which extend you can access USB from within iOS. If you need details about that, AskDifferent is the wrong place to ask (see the [faq]).

Comment: Where is the right place to asl then?

Comment: @Fiend Are you a dev?

Comment: I have knowledge of computer science and programming.